# What is the term for xml elements of type <Something />

Tags: xml, terminology

What is the terminology for an element like `<Something />` ?
I called it self terminating element, but then it only seemed natural (lly wrong maybe).

Also is there a term to distinguish a simple element

```
<Something>abc</Something>
```

from

```
<ns3:Something>yxz</ns3:Something>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntactic form `<something/>` is correctly called an *empty-element tag*.

Note that this is really a property of the tag, not of the element; the element represented by `<something/>` is indistinguishable from the element represented by `<something></something>`, so by the time you move from the world of tags to the world of elements, the distinction is lost.

The element `<x>aaa</x>` (as opposed to `<p:x>aaa</p:x>`) is probably best referred to as a *no-namespace element* -- provided that there's no default namespace in scope on some containing element. But you won't find that term in the Namespaces specification; the closest it gets is *"an element with an expanded name whose namespace name has no value"*, which is hopelessly unwieldy.